# How and where I can deploy my Flask app build on my local machine and connected to my local mysql-server?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-mysql

I have a flask app with simple functionalities of a blog website codes given in below Github repo -

https://github.com/vivanks/flaskhost

It's data like user login details and blogs are stored in my system MySql-server.

On local machine it's working perfectly fine.

Now I want it to be deployed over internet.

What I tried so far is :

1. Heroku but problem with heroku is it need some postgressql and my whole data is stored in MySQL so I can't conver it.
2. Hosting flask part on Heroku and Database on 000webhost.com but 000webhost don't allow to connect to database outside of 00webhost
3. Hosting on http://pythonanywhere.com/ but then again failed also It don't support `import MySQLdb` instead it supports `sqlalchemy`

I want some way or something stable way through which I can export my data stored in mysql and don't have to change my code.

It would be great if you provide step by step guide.

P.S I don't have problem paying small amount

Comment: This question is more suited to https://serverfault.com, but have a look at VPS providers such as [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/one-clicks/django/) or [Amazon AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/codestar/features/).

Comment: SQLAlchemy allows you to port MySQLDb into your app. Please read the docs.

Comment: for pythonanywhere you can just `pip install mysqlclient`